# How would I append tags separately in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, id3

How would I change the following code so instead of appending all tags for files together, every separate tag is stored individually, for example 'Title' would be stored within $title? Because all the tags at the moment are being stored within $aTags

The code:

```
// gathering all mp3 files in 'mp3' folder into array
$sDir = 'mp3/';
$aFiles = array();
$rDir = opendir($sDir);
if ($rDir) {
while ($sFile = readdir($rDir)) {
    if ($sFile == '.' or $sFile == '..' or !is_file($sDir . $sFile))
        continue;

    $aPathInfo = pathinfo($sFile);
    $sExt = strtolower($aPathInfo['extension']);
    if ($sExt == 'mp3') {
        $aFiles[] = $sDir . $sFile;
  }
}
closedir($rDir);
}

// new object of our ID3TagsReader class
$oReader = new ID3TagsReader();

// passing through located files ..
$sList = $sList2 = '';
foreach ($aFiles as $sSingleFile) {
$aTags = $oReader->getTagsInfo($sSingleFile); // obtaining ID3 tags info
$sList .= '<tr><td>'.$aTags['Title'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Album'].'</td>
<td>'.$aTags['Author'].'</td>
                <td>'.$aTags['AlbumAuthor'].'</td>
<td>'.$aTags['Track'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Year'].'</td>
                <td>'.$aTags['Lenght'].'</td><td>'.$aTags['Lyric'].'</td>
<td>'.$aTags['Desc'].'</td>
                <td>'.$aTags['Genre'].'</td></tr>';


}
```

Comment: are you using the Git class or the example found here : https://www.script-tutorials.com/id3-tags-reader-with-php/ ?

Comment: nah not git class, I need the variables to be different as I want to store the data into a database?

Comment: im not sure how you can append a file at a time to the database

Comment: What benefit would this bring?  Seems that would be counter productive.

Comment: im not sure how I would append each $aTags variable and assign them in their associated heading in the database?

Comment: Database? Your question says nothing about a database.